# Nginx 400 Bad Request with Python Flask on Linux Server

Tags: python, linux, pandas, nginx, flask

I have a python flask program which is running on my local windows pc perfectly. When I send a request with postman it works fine. Then I published it on my linux server. My application service "systemctl status service" output was like in the below: [image]

Then I changed my code. My now it seems fine:
[image]

But when I send a request from postman it's response is **"400 Bad Request"**

My codes related part is:

```
def read_file(unknown_count, file_data):
    file = pd.read_csv(file_data, sep=';', header=None)
    df = pd.DataFrame(file)
    solve(df, unknown_count)

@app.route("/find", methods = ['POST'])
def findroots():
    unknowns = int(request.form['unknowns'])
    file_data = request.files['file']
    read_file(unknowns, file_data)
    return send_file('roots.csv', mimetype='text/csv', as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I'm taking a csv file and a variable value from request form-data and then I convert the csv file to dataframe in my read_file() function. Then I'm calculating somethings and then write the result to a csv file and I'm sending it as a response.

```
def solve(df, unknown_count):
    //here is my some codes
    to_csv(roots)

def to_csv(roots):
    root_vals = []
    for i, root_cluster in enumerate(roots):
        //here is some codes which is doesn't matter
        root_vals.append(root_val)
    
    dfr = pd.DataFrame(root_vals)
    dfr.to_csv('roots.csv', index = False, header=None)
```

As I said it's work fine on my local computer. But when I'm trying to send a request to my app which is running on linux server. It returns 400 Bad request. Maybe the reason is still read_csv. But I'm trying to deal it for 7 hours. Finally I decided to ask it in there. I deleted my all files and deploy it again.

Here is my nginx config:
[image]

Here is my service:

But still the same. Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you export your Postman request to `curl` and share? What the permission of the `roots.csv`? Is this file readable / writeable from the user your flask app is running on?

Comment: @TimoStark Here is my request _curl --location --request POST 'http://serverip:serverport/find' \
--header 'Content-Length: <calculated when request is sent>' \
--form 'file=@"/C:/Users/Fordev/Downloads/myfile.csv"' \
--form 'unknowns="14"'_ And unfortunatelly my roots.csv can't create cause i guess it's crashes on read_file() function. I guess it can't read the file_data

Comment: Good thing about Python and Flask is you can wirte to stdout and stderr while testing it on your linux box. Give it a try and see where your app is failing. If you want drop the flask app to a gist maybe I can clone it and run it later tonight.

Comment: Just a small question :) Where does nginx comes to play?? Do you have a proxy in between your flak app / gunicorn app server and your client?

Comment: Actually i wrote a service which is create a .sock file. In nginx "sites-available" there is aline like: proxy_pass http://unix/pathofsockfile/file.sock;

Comment: Ahhhhhh that changes A LOT! Please update your question and add the nginx configuration as well as the error and access log right after your request. If NGINX is returning a 400 Bad Request it will send the reason to the error_log. Make sure log level is info or debug in your nginx config.

Comment: I checked my nginx logs and also my service logs. There is no error seems. I edited my question.  Also can I communicate with you from another platform for send my logs?

Comment: Check my profile and send me a DM on twitter. Will share my discord handle.

Comment: I think you don't receive messages from peoples that you don't follow cause your settings. So I can't send dm from twitter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230370/discussion-between-timo-stark-and-fordev).

Answer (score 2):

Your Nginx configuration looks correct.

You can use `sudo nginx -T`to print the currently loaded configuration. Make sure you are reloading the configuration after making changes `sudo nginx -s reload`

You can simply check if your server-block will be reached with this configuration snip-it:

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  server_name 1.2.3.4;

  location / {
    return 200 "Hello from the other side... \n";
  }
}
```

This should print out `hello from ...` as a result of

`curl -v http://1.2.3.4:8081`